# TypeScript Web-Based IDE

Tags: javascript, ide, typescript

Given the fact that TypeScript is Open Source, is [this Web-Based IDE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) also available as a tool that can be downloaded anywhere?

I'm developing a web application in which the client can write a user-defined expression (with user-defined variables and predefined methods) which is evaluated, compiled and used at runtime on the server using C# .Net. Using TypeScript and its wonderful web-based editor's features like syntax or error highlighting, code completion, method signature suggestion, etc,  saves me lots of trouble in the user interface.

So is this editor also part of TypeScript? If not, is there any other open source solutions with similar capabilities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update 2017: The [Monaco editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) used in the TypeScript Playground has been made available on GitHub.

You can also take a look at [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), for a more out-of-browser experience.

There is also a [TypeScript editor build on the ACE Editor](https://github.com/hi104/typescript-playground-on-ace), which is also on GitHub.

Answer (score 10):

There are some web IDEs with support of TypeScript, namely:

- [Cloud9](https://c9.io/site/blog/2012/10/typescript-support-in-cloud9/)
- [CATS](http://jbaron.github.com/cats/)
- [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/?javascript) (choose TypeScript from dropdown)
- [Baz](https://github.com/nxn/baz)

If you think about making a new one, you could base on one of my 2 projects: [TypeScript Compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) or [TypeScript Interpret](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-interpret) ;)

Comment: TouchDevelop is written in TypesScript, but does not support it, it has its own language instead.

Comment: Cloud9 is not offering TypeScript currently. The blog entry linked no longer exist.

Answer (score 3):

The editor used on the playground is informally known as `Monaco` and it's used in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

*UPDATE 11.22.2015:*
Visual Studio Code is now open source, which means we have access to the source of the Monaco Editor. I think this should now give us the ability to use the Monaco Editor in a browser, I'm [waiting on a response](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/446) to my question in the VS Code repostiroy.

> The 'editor' (the thing that renders the code with syntax highlighting, line numbers, etc..) part of Visual Studio Code is Microsoft's Monaco editor. It is the same editor used for OneDrive, Windows Azure, TypeScript Playground, and Visual Studio Online. I have yet to find any real documentation on this editor from Microsoft but there are some articles about it around the web.

Read more about Visual Studio Code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29966094/1571103).

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation of it which is open source:

https://github.com/jbaron/typescript-playground-on-ace

Comment: I've forked this and made my own more advanced version with the latest typescript 1.5 support: https://github.com/drake7707/Typescript-Editor

Answer (score 1):

there is goormIDE which is also cloud IDE
this is open source or service version

- http://goorm.io
- http://github.com/xenoz0718/goorm

if you use node.js, just type this command

```
$ npm install goorm -g
```

Answer (score 1):

I've played with TypeScript Compiler API both in node.js and in the browser. Also with monaco-editor:

- Playground and COmpiler API examples 100% in the browser https://cancerberosgx.github.io/typescript-in-the-browser/typescript-compiler/
- TS compiler examples and playground which are evaluated in the server: https://typescript-api-playground.glitch.me
- And an effort (WIP) to build a TS project editor using monaco-editor and typescript 100% in the browser.
- more info here: https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/typescript-in-the-browser

yes, TypeScript and monaco editor look good, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides a VM with Root so you can install whatever tools you need, and in this case, TypeScript via `npm install -g typescript`.

VM Domain and Apache is included, so previewing your work in your browser is also easy :)

Answer (score 0):

For very simple stuff you can try out 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/typescript-editey/liedfkjkedgcgpddoijfeeeeoikcbmaf

Your typescript files will be converted to a js file on the fly and your site will be hosted for free on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CATS, and I really like it because of two things:

- The IDE is not so bad. It does it job done, and once you practice with it, you'll like it!
- It's portable

THe last is the feature I like the most, because I don't have to install anything (at least, under Windows), and you don't need Visual Studio (it's around 9 Gb and two hours installing).

The TypeScript Playground is a nice editor, but if you need to test small scripts, or want to try something that can be done only in one file!

Answer (score 0):

The editor for the Typescript Playground is called Monaco, and it's available on GH / npm / etc.

http://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor

https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor

Answer (score 0):

As TypeScript's playground source code has not been made available until now, I've published an implementation—also based on the [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor)—with some enhancements regarding compiler options and code execution:

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/fabiandev/typescript-playground
Online Playground: https://fabiandev.github.io/typescript-playground/

Answer (score 0):

The following cloud IDEs have decent TypeScript support:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)
- [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)